# How to know which file is being sent in POST request by Android device?

Tags: android, http-proxy

I am using an Android Device. 
I make apps and generally use Burp Proxy to try to debug how my app's requests-response works.

Recently I have noticed some anonymous request being sent by my device which shows some zip files being sent from my device continuously at particular time intervals in POST requests. Everything is encoded in some format.

How can I detect what is being sent?

The request (POST data) somewhat looks like below :

> --EPHOfJ4y8TYXsrsxhfux4TMbMGEjJU
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mpk"; filename="Ju81TNEP4xi2naF.zip"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> Zµòo¨T
>   ²&Z@=ÌDS'èpo^¿=ùùÄ+µ¼H$A÷¼~Ô¢Øûºe¨3Ãì4{!W-VçN÷ê÷?Ö\'5;ù×ómøý`Û2=ÜÏòµlyËË7´ÃM­E$C°Ýo@
>   0 ÅJ²J&ÔLlÅÖ<rÜÜy`®1'BÓöÙhy¨D¨Q
>   º
>
> --EPHOfJ4y8TYXsrsxhfux4TMbMGEjJU--

Any help is highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Since the filename is .zip, have you copied it out to a file and tried to unzip it?

Comment: how do I get hold of this file ? I don't have any such file on device. The file is being generated with random names.

Comment: The file is right there - the first byte is 0x5A, or 'Z'.  You should read up on [MIME messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).  You'll want to use a tool that lets you look at the raw bytes, as trying to reverse-engineer them based on what wacky character it got displayed as is painful.

Comment: Thanks @gowenfawr 
I am going to try what you have said. Will get back to you if I need help.